# Get full access to printer using Python or Java

Tags: java, python, printing, raspberry-pi

Can we use Python or Java (my priority is Python) to write a program that runs on Raspberry Pi and has control over our printer: i.e. just by pushing a button on Raspberry Pi, the printer do the nozzle check, or head cleaning.

Is it possible ?

And what language (Python/Java) is most suitable in doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is most likely *possible* via both Python and Java.

It comes down to sending the proper command to the printer via USB.

First steps:

- Learn something about how USB works
- Use something like Wireshark to listen to the traffic on your USB bus while you run nozzle check/head cleaning/etc. via printer driver
- Try to replicate this traffic from language of your choice